# Vimeo Froogaloop - fullscreen availability detection HTML5 player JS API

Tags: javascript, html, vimeo, vimeo-player, froogaloop

Question is pretty simple, as I understand `Vimeo` users can determine will `fullscreen` button be availible for their video embeds or not.
I'm wondering is there a way to check from `JavaScript Froogaloop API` if there is fullscreen button availible or not, or maybe I can override those settings and set `fullscreen` off for any video?